# Xcode 8 / Swift 3 - Type 'CGColorRenderingIntent' has no member 'RenderingIntentDefault'

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8

I've successfully converted many errors to Swift 3 except for the last line. It works in Xcode 7 but not Xcode 8.

It's also worth noting that Xcode 7 has documentation on `CGColorRenderingIntent` but Xcode 8 doesn't.

> Type 'CGColorRenderingIntent' has no member 'RenderingIntentDefault'

Code I'm working with:

```
import CoreImage

// omitted code

public func imageFromPixels(pixels: ([Pixel], width: Int, height: Int)) -> CIImage {
let bitsPerComponent = 8
let bitsPerPixel = 32
let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue) // alpha is last
let providerRef = CGDataProvider(data: NSData(bytes: pixels.0, length: pixels.0.count * sizeof(Pixel)))
let image = CGImageCreate(pixels.1, pixels.2, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, pixels.1 * sizeof(Pixel), rgbColorSpace, bitmapInfo, providerRef!, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)
return CIImage(CGImage: image!)
}
```

Apple documentation:

```
enum CGColorRenderingIntent : Int32 {
case RenderingIntentDefault
case RenderingIntentAbsoluteColorimetric
case RenderingIntentRelativeColorimetric
case RenderingIntentPerceptual
case RenderingIntentSaturation
}
```

Updated Code:

```
let image = CGImage(width: pixels.1,
                    height: pixels.2,
                    bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
                    bitsPerPixel: bitsPerPixel,
                    bytesPerRow: pixels.1 * sizeof(Pixel),
                    space: rgbColorSpace,
                    bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo,
                    provider: providerRef!,
                    decode: nil,
                    shouldInterpolate: true,
                    intent: .defaultIntent)

return CGImage(CGImage: image!) //  Incorrect argument label in call (have 'CGImage:', expected 'copy:')
```

Comment: Typo: `return CIImage(cgImage: ...` with **I**

Comment: Whatever docs you're looking at are old. If you google a symbol and find your way to a URL that starts with developer.apple.com/library/, you're in the docs for shipping OS and Swift 2. The Swift 3 / Xcode 8 / associated OS beta docs for that enum are [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgcolorrenderingintent).

Comment: Yeah that was just a type I had for the return. The main problem was finding the case name for the `CGColorRenderingIntent` enum. I always cmd-click whatever I'm having trouble with but for some reason my Xcode 8 is only giving me `grey question marks` or `no docs` message. I'm surprised this was released even as a beta because every time I change something it takes a good 10 seconds for the error to update. I am clicking `Build` every 30 seconds it seems to get a proper display of all my errors. Every few seconds my color coding disappears too.

Comment: It seems like you were working on Raytracing with Swift Playground tutorial. The syntax has changed so much since it was published. In this case could you please send me your finished code via github?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>⌘-click</kbd> on the symbol `CGColorRenderingIntent` and you will see

> ```
> public enum CGColorRenderingIntent : Int32 {
>
>   case defaultIntent
>   case absoluteColorimetric
>   case relativeColorimetric
>   case perceptual
>   case saturation 
> }
> ```

So it's

```
let image = CGImage(width: pixels.1, 
                   height: pixels.2, 
         bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, 
             bitsPerPixel: bitsPerPixel, 
              bytesPerRow: pixels.1 * sizeof(Pixel), 
                    space: rgbColorSpace, 
               bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo, 
                 provider: providerRef!, 
                   decode: nil, 
        shouldInterpolate: true, 
                   intent: .defaultIntent)

return CIImage(cgImage: image!)
```

even the initializers of `CGImage` and `CIImage` have been changed.

Comment: Hi. I just updated my question to say that common-click doesn't work on `CGColorRenderingIntent` in Xcode 8. At least for me it doesn't. I just get a question mark. http://imgur.com/kjLECld. And even though I get an error with the CGImage like you said auto-complete only gives me CGImage. Is something messed up with my Xcode? Xcode 7 is also open. Is that causing issues? Also Xcode 8 is VERY slow is updating errors. Like 10 seconds.

Comment: I updated the answer. Actually the compiler should give you suggestions what to do (it does on my machine). I'd discourage from running both Xcode versions at the same time.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, sorry. that last `CIImage` got me. Thanks. Ok so zero errors now. Only problem is the image tracer doesn't run haha. Wow.  Here is what it's supposed to look like. http://i.imgur.com/vSulmar.png. But Xcode 8 is just blank. It's really a shame because I wanted to put it in an iOS 10 Playground. Oh well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Btw, even when I cmd-click on CIImage or CGImage I don't get any Xcode Version 8.0 beta (8S128d) deep links to docs/parent class. What would be causing this? Should I be on macOS 10.12 beta as well?

Comment: Got it working. For some reason Xcode 8 is taking like a minute or a restart to display error updates. Therefore I couldn't know I had new errors. After I restarted Xcode 8 only then did it show me two last errors I had to fix. Image Tracer is finally working.